# How to get the message size of Exchange Online using Microsoft Graph Api?

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api, office365-restapi

I am using graph.microsoft.com to fetch the exchange online folders and messages. But I am not getting the size of the message and folders in the response. Is there any way to get the message size using the graph Api. Although the size of the attachments is returned in the response.
Another problem I am facing is I am not able to fetch all the folders in a mailbox. I was able to fetch all the folders using Exchange Web Service. I have checked the permission level of the folders which were not fetched by the graph api but there was no any such subtle differences when I compared them with the discovered ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Message`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#RESTAPIResourcesMessage) entity doesn't have a size property. You could suggest one at http://officespdev.uservoice.com/.

You should be able to get folders, as long as their visible to normal clients. Which folders can you not get?

Comment: Thanks Jason for your reply. Right now I am able to get the public folders but somehow I am not able to fetch the system folders.
I am using below link to fetch the folders:-
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders

Comment: Yes we do not expose system folders via the API.

Comment: Can you provide some logic to calculate the message size manually ?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the message size by expanding the "PidTagMessageSize" extended property, in the following way:

GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/*USER@MyOrg.onmicrosoft.com*/messages/**?$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'LONG 0x0E08')**

For extra information:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842471.aspx

Comment: Legend! Thanks this worked great. Only thing is `PropertyId` should be `Id`. `$filter=Id eq 'LONG 0x0E08'`

Answer (score 4):

### For Microsoft Graph API v1.0

Sharon's answer will need to be tweaked and the URL becomes

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=Id eq 'LONG 0x0E08')
```

Exchange Server Protocols Master Property List: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/f6ab1613-aefe-447d-a49c-18217230b148

Comment: Hi, is the message size located on singleValueExtendedProperties.value?

Answer (score 0):

For people trying to understand how and why propertyId is `Long 0x0E08`, please read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/f6ab1613-aefe-447d-a49c-18217230b148. Each field has a property id, like

```
Description: Contains the size, in bytes, consumed by the Message object on the server.
Property ID: 0x0E08
Data type: PtypInteger32, 0x0003
```