# How to get the message size of Office 365 using Microsoft Graph Api?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

There is [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896696/how-to-get-the-message-size-of-exchange-online-using-microsoft-graph-api) asked in 2016 about same topic. Answer says to run query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=Id eq 'LONG 0x0E08')
```

If I run MS Graph query message size is not returned. $expand is ignored. I get same response as it would not be specified.
How to get message size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*Documentation*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) explains reason why I did not get size
"*Make sure you apply URL encoding to the space characters in the filter string.*"
I changed URL to

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=Id%20eq%20'LONG%200x0E08')
```

I got message size in bytes

```
"singleValueExtendedProperties@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('XXXX')/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages('AAAAA')/singleValueExtendedProperties",
"singleValueExtendedProperties": [
    {
        "id": "Long 0xe08",
        "value": "100265"
    }
]
```