# How can I get the size of a mail (and attachments) in ExchangeOnline using Powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail, powershell-5.1

The wider context of this is that I am trying to write some powershell code to extract a listing of the contents of my Office 365 mailbox in CSV form *including the size of each item* to help me to do some subsequent analysis of where the storage in my mailbox is being consumed. I can see how this functionality would also lead onto other useful tools.

I discovered this sample/POC code by Aleksandr Reznik [EXchangeOnline2CSV](https://github.com/AleksandrReznik/EXchangeOnline2CSV) this got me a lot of the way there. However I've been unable to successfully extend it to extract the mail size (in bytes).

[I found this similar question using the graph.microsoft.com API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896696/how-to-get-the-message-size-of-exchange-online-using-microsoft-graph-api). And from that I've inferred (perhaps wrongly) that the powershell module i'm using (Microsoft.Graph.Mail) is obtaining it's data from the same source and that message size is a "single value extended property" of a mail object.

The Powershell MS Graph Docs are a bit sparse, however they have a cmdlet that seems to be the right candidate for interfacing with this data [Get-MgUserMessageSingleValueExtendedProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.mail/get-mgusermessagesinglevalueextendedproperty?view=graph-powershell-1.0)

I've also found similar code in the Exch-Rest source that looks like it's doing what I need (in a way I admit I don't quite understand) but that has given me hope that what I'm trying to do is actually possible. This code includes a call to extract the "MessageSize" using the same Propety ID from above "0x0E08"
[Get-EXRKnownProps](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Exch-Rest/3.24.0/Content/functions%5Cother%5CGet-EXRKnownProps.ps1) and [Get-EXRTaggedProperty](https://github.com/gscales/Exch-Rest/blob/55d1198d1d0ee7d90d090565cc7661e85ae4a849/functions/other/Get-EXRTaggedProperty.ps1) doesn't seem to be doing anything too peculiar to extract it (although I don't quite follow all of it).

My attempts at trying to get `Get-MgUserMessageSingleValueExtendedProperty` to return anything at all have been pretty futile however.

I feel like this is either a "it hasn't been implemented yet" or a "you're missing a semi-colon" type issue but at this point my google-fu has failed me and I can find no examples of what I'm trying to do so would appreciate any help.

Powershell - 5.1.19041.1682
Microsoft.Graph - 1.16.0

Here's some butchered code that I have been using to make the connection and test the `Get-MgUserMessageSingleValueExtendedProperty` cmdlet, including in the inline comments the errors it has been returning.

(UPN changed obviously, however this works for me and returns sensible values for Subject for example)

`

```
$UPN ="user@domain.com"

Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Mail.Read"
$folders = Get-MgUserMailFolder -UserId $UPN -All
write-host "Current folders:"
$folders.DisplayName
$folder = $folders | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq "Inbox" }

$mails = Get-MgUserMailFolderMessage -All -UserId $UPN  -MailFolderId $folder.Id -Top 1
Write-Host "No. Of Emails: $($mails.count)"

foreach($currEmail in $mails){
    Write-Host "Subject: $($currEmail.Subject)"     
    
    # PidTagMessageSize = 0x0E08
    # Can't get the right form for the following....
    
    $mailSizeInBytes = Get-MgUserMessageSingleValueExtendedProperty -InputObject $currEmail -Property "0x0E08"
    # Errors as Get-MgUserMessageSingleValueExtendedProperty : The pipeline has been stopped.
  
    $mailSizeInBytes = Get-MgUserMessageSingleValueExtendedProperty  -MessageId $currEmail.Id -UserId $UPN -Property "0x0E08"
    # Errors as Get-MgUserMessageSingleValueExtendedProperty : Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: An identifier was expected at position 0.
    
    $mailSizeInBytes = Get-MgUserMessageSingleValueExtendedProperty  -MessageId $currEmail.Id -UserId $UPN -Property "LONG 0x0E08"
    # Errors as Get-MgUserMessageSingleValueExtendedProperty : Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Term 'LONG 0x0E08' is not valid in a $select or $expand expression.

    Write-Host "Mail Size: $($mailSizeInBytes)"
}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the -expandproperty in Get-MgUserMailFolderMessage which will equate to an $expand in the Graph request eg

```
$mails = Get-MgUserMailFolderMessage -All -UserId user@domain  -MailFolderId Inbox -Top 1 -ExpandProperty "singleValueExtendedProperties(`$filter=id eq 'long 0x0E08')"
```

then

```
$mails.SingleValueExtendedProperties[0]
```

Comment: Brilliant, this worked for me. I had to use `$mails.SingleValueExtendedProperties[0].Value` to grab the actual figure, but this approach worked and extended to multiple mail items as well.